# Does Dash.js plays .m3u8 playlist

Tags: javascript, html, streaming, html5-video, dash.js

This is my first time I'm working with dash.js and I want to know if I can play .m3u8 playlist with dash.js. If not can you suggest another way of doing it.

Comment: have you tried? according to the specs Dash.js is targeted at mpeg-dash manifests, not HLS (so mpd, not m3u8) so you might be better off looking at something more generic like plyr.io

Answer (score 2):

No, dash.js only supports MPEG-DASH.
See https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki for more information on dash.js.

M3U8 playlists are used in HLS which is a different streaming format. If you google "hls html5 player" you'll find a variety of open-source and commercial solutions to choose from.

Comment: Thanks for your response.